# JSTreeGrid cell editing on selection

Tags: jstree

I am using [jsTreeGrid](https://github.com/deitch/jstree-grid) to do a row edit on a selection using this action..

```
function demo_rename() {
    var ref = $('#jstree_demo').jstree(true),
        sel = ref.get_selected();

    if(!sel.length) {
        return false;
    }

    sel = sel[0];
    ref.edit(sel);
};
```

How I can edit a cell on selection using the same jsTreeGrid library?

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines after `set = sel[0];`:

```
var column_number = 1; //assume second column
var current_value = $("#jsgrid_" + sel + "_col"+ column_number +" > span").html();
$("#jsgrid_" + sel + "_col"+ column_number +" > span").html("<input type='text' value='"+ current_value +"' />");

$("#jsgrid_" + sel + "_col"+ column_number +" > span > input").keypress(function(e){
     if(e.keyCode)
     {
         var new_value = $(this).val();
         $(this).parent().html(new_value);
     }
});
```

and remove `ref.edit(sel);`